# Intern keyboard tests have stopped working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, intern

I have a test written with intern that worked fine on Firefox and Chrome until recently - possibly until a recent upgrade of intern. The following code correctly tabbed to an element on the screen that can be focussed, and when actioned with the [Space] key would cause a script event to trigger.

```
.keys(specialKeys.Tab)
.keys(specialKeys["Space"])
.end()
```

If I do this activity manually in either browser it works fine.

Now when I run this sequence of commands it works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I have tried forcing an update of both Chrome and ChromeDriver and running again. This has not fixed the problem.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is occurring?

I'm using intern 1.7, Chrome 34.0.1847.137 and ChromeDriver 2.10.0. If there is a particular sequence of npm commands that gives a reliable and stable installation when one of the afore mentioned components upgrades that would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Chrome 34, caused by keyboard focus being stuck on the address bar. It is not a bug in Intern. More information can be found at https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=762.